# RestSharp & Framework configuration in SSIS

Tags: ssis, restsharp

So I started with VS2017, SQL 2017. 
Created a script task which by default is .Net 4.5, and installed RestSharp.
Error.RestSharp needs 4.5.2, so I changed my framework in VSTA and hey-presto, everything installed, built and saved.

Now, close VSTA, close the script task, then reopen both - only to find that the project has reset to .Net 4.5. References to RestSharp are now invalid.

After some googling, someone said that when using SQL2017 the framework in SSIS gets fixed to 4.5.
So, I changed to SQL2019, now only to find that the framework gets fixed to 4.6 - which causes the same errors as previous.
By behaviour, it looks like RestSharp only works with very specific versions on framework, and that is not configurable in VS !!?

Anyone have any ideas ??
Thanks

Comment: Whenever I use add-ins, I started using a Console App. But I'll warn you, once you start using a console app, you might find yourself further and further away from SSIS to solve problems.

Comment: 4.6 is _higher_ than 4.5.2, so any project that targets 4.6 can use RestSharp that targets 4.5.2.